# npgsql scaffold-DbContext error

Tags: entity-framework-core, npgsql

When reverse engineer an entityframework model from the database using EntityFrameworkCore and the Scaffold-DbContext command I get the following error:

Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80000405): 42703 : column "start_value" does not exist

Why am I getting this error?  Shouldn't the Scaffold command only give me columns that are in the database?

Edit 3/29/2017

Here is the Scaffold-DbContext Error:

Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42703: column "start_value" does not exist
    at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.DoReadMessage(DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean isPrependedMessage)
    at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ReadMessageWithPrepended(DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode)
    at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ReadExpectingT
    at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResultInternal()
    at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult()
    at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.Execute(CommandBehavior behavior)
    at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior)
    at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseModelFactory.GetSequences()
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseModelFactory.Create(DbConnection connection, TableSelectionSet tableSelectionSet)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, TableSelectionSet tableSelectionSet)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, TableSelectionSet tableSelectionSet)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.NpgsqlScaffoldingModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, TableSelectionSet tableSelectionSet)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ReverseEngineeringGenerator.GetMetadataModel(ReverseEngineeringConfiguration configuration)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ReverseEngineeringGenerator.GenerateAsync(ReverseEngineeringConfiguration configuration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DatabaseOperations.ScaffoldContextAsync(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas, IEnumerable`1 tables, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.d__22.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass4_0`1.b__0()
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
42703: column "start_value" does not exist

Here is the logfile from PostgresSQL:

ERROR:  column "start_value" does not exist at character 58
STATEMENT:
        SELECT
            sequence_schema, sequence_name, data_type, start_value::bigint, minimum_value::bigint, maximum_value::bigint, increment::int,
            CASE WHEN cycle_option = 'YES' THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END,
            ownerns.nspname AS owner_schema,
            tblcls.relname AS owner_table,
            attname AS owner_column
        FROM information_schema.sequences
        JOIN pg_namespace AS seqns ON seqns.nspname = sequence_schema
        JOIN pg_class AS seqcls ON seqcls.relnamespace = seqns.oid AND seqcls.relname = sequence_name AND seqcls.relkind = 'S'
        LEFT OUTER JOIN pg_depend AS dep ON dep.objid = seqcls.oid AND deptype='a'
        LEFT OUTER JOIN pg_class AS tblcls ON tblcls.oid = dep.refobjid
        LEFT OUTER JOIN pg_attribute AS att ON attrelid = dep.refobjid AND attnum = dep.refobjsubid
        LEFT OUTER JOIN pg_namespace AS ownerns ON ownerns.oid = tblcls.relnamespace

Thanks

Comment: Can you please pg_dump your database and post a link to it so it can be reproduced and checked?

Comment: I cannot provide the dump since that computer/server is not connected to the internet nor can documents be copied off it.  I will look at the dump.  Is there anything that I should be looking for in particular?  What version of PostgresSQL is the Scaffold command useful?

Comment: Hmm... Before inspecting the dump, any chance you can look at PostgreSQL's server-side logs to see what is exactly what is being executed that triggers the error? Also, if you can post the full stack trace for the exception that may help.

Comment: I edited my post with the PostgresSQL logfile and also the Scaffold command errors